# Update statement with settting value for attribute by selecting max from the same table doesn't work

Tags: database, oracle11g

i want to update some value say x in a table by taking max value of X and adding 1 to it.

the below update doesn't work for me.

```
update table set x=select max(x)+1 where y='some value'
```

Can anyone suggest any ways for it?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to update _all_ x? Not a specific row? The easiest way to explain is probably some sample data and a desired result.

Comment: my mistake, the rows to be update are based on certain conditions added to it, so that only selected rows get updated.
update table set x=(select max(x) from table)+1 where y='some value'

Comment: [What's not working?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93e41/1).

Comment: Actually the issue was in hibernate HQL generating this update statement, the above query executed fine.

Comment: however the result was not as expected. suppose data is as below
x1 2
x1 3
x2 4
x3 5
then the update is giving the below output
x1 5
x1 5
x2 5
x3 5
All values are getting updated to max of the X column.
Can you please help in this?

Comment: That's what I was asking before, you said you wanted a condition on `y` to update the row, since `y` is the same for all rows in your example, all rows will be updated. Please add sample data and a desired result to your question so that I can understand what you really want, and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: The sample data which you have used is correct. only in the output i needed that x keeps on incrementing by 1 of max value at the point of time and not get set to same value as before.

Comment: Still unclear, exactly _what_ value should be updated by incrementing if not all matching values? Please add a sample to your query showing what you mean.